# Oracle goldengate service is not starting: Failed to retrieve the name of a missing Oracle redo log

Tags: oracle, oracle-12c, goldengate

I am trying to start GG service, when try 'start my_service' then starting but it didn't start, status is changed always starting to stopped.
I need to start goldengate service.. I don't know what happened its service and what should set to solve the problem. Help me guys

My service name is: MY_SERVICE

HERE ARE LOG:

```
 2020-02-17 14:52:37  INFO    OGG-00987  Oracle GoldenGate Command Interpreter for Oracle:  GGSCI command (oracle): start MY_SERVICE.
2020-02-17 14:52:37  INFO    OGG-00963  Oracle GoldenGate Manager for Oracle, mgr.prm:  Command received from GGSCI on host [192.168.1.100 ]:37022 (START EXTRACT MY_SERVICE ).
2020-02-17 14:52:37  INFO    OGG-00960  Oracle GoldenGate Manager for Oracle, mgr.prm:  Access granted (rule #6).
2020-02-17 14:52:37  INFO    OGG-00975  Oracle GoldenGate Manager for Oracle, mgr.prm:  EXTRACT MY_SERVICE starting.
2020-02-17 14:52:37  INFO    OGG-00992  Oracle GoldenGate Capture for Oracle, MY_SERVICE.prm:  EXTRACT MY_SERVICE starting.
2020-02-17 14:52:37  INFO    OGG-03059  Oracle GoldenGate Capture for Oracle, MY_SERVICE.prm:  Operating system character set identified as UTF-8.
2020-02-17 14:52:37  INFO    OGG-02695  Oracle GoldenGate Capture for Oracle, MY_SERVICE.prm:  ANSI SQL parameter syntax is used for parameter parsing.
2020-02-17 14:52:37  INFO    OGG-02095  Oracle GoldenGate Capture for Oracle, MY_SERVICE.prm:  Successfully set environment variable NLS_LANG=AMERICAN_AMERICA.AL32UTF8.
2020-02-17 14:52:37  INFO    OGG-02095  Oracle GoldenGate Capture for Oracle, MY_SERVICE.prm:  Successfully set environment variable ORACLE_SID=MYSNAME.
2020-02-17 14:52:37  INFO    OGG-02095  Oracle GoldenGate Capture for Oracle, MY_SERVICE.prm:  Successfully set environment variable ORACLE_HOME=/u01/app/oracle/product/12.1.0/db_1.
2020-02-17 14:52:37  INFO    OGG-02095  Oracle GoldenGate Capture for Oracle, MY_SERVICE.prm:  Successfully set environment variable NLS_LANG=AMERICAN_AMERICA.AL32UTF8.
2020-02-17 14:52:37  INFO    OGG-02095  Oracle GoldenGate Capture for Oracle, MY_SERVICE.prm:  Successfully set environment variable ORACLE_SID=MYSNAME.
2020-02-17 14:52:37  INFO    OGG-02095  Oracle GoldenGate Capture for Oracle, MY_SERVICE.prm:  Successfully set environment variable ORACLE_HOME=/u01/app/oracle/product/12.1.0/db_1.
2020-02-17 14:52:38  INFO    OGG-03522  Oracle GoldenGate Capture for Oracle, MY_SERVICE.prm:  Setting session time zone to source database time zone 'GMT'.
2020-02-17 14:52:38  INFO    OGG-01815  Oracle GoldenGate Capture for Oracle, MY_SERVICE.prm:  Virtual Memory Facilities for: BR
    anon alloc: mmap(MAP_ANON)  anon free: munmap
    file alloc: mmap(MAP_SHARED)  file free: munmap
    target directories:
    /u01/ogg/BR/MY_SERVICE.
2020-02-17 14:52:38  INFO    OGG-01851  Oracle GoldenGate Capture for Oracle, MY_SERVICE.prm:  filecaching started: thread ID: 140383342216960.
2020-02-17 14:52:38  INFO    OGG-01815  Oracle GoldenGate Capture for Oracle, MY_SERVICE.prm:  Virtual Memory Facilities for: COM
    anon alloc: mmap(MAP_ANON)  anon free: munmap
    file alloc: mmap(MAP_SHARED)  file free: munmap
    target directories:
    /u01/ogg/dirtmp.
2020-02-17 14:52:38  INFO    OGG-01639  Oracle GoldenGate Capture for Oracle, MY_SERVICE.prm:  BOUNDED RECOVERY:  ACTIVE: for object pool 1: p49266_extr.
2020-02-17 14:52:38  INFO    OGG-01640  Oracle GoldenGate Capture for Oracle, MY_SERVICE.prm:  BOUNDED RECOVERY: recovery start XID: 0.0.0.
2020-02-17 14:52:38  INFO    OGG-01641  Oracle GoldenGate Capture for Oracle, MY_SERVICE.prm:  BOUNDED RECOVERY: recovery start position: SeqNo: 11932, RBA: 25311476, SCN: 1.353105371 (4648072667), Timestamp: 2019-12-30 16:06:40.000000, Thread: 2.
2020-02-17 14:52:38  INFO    OGG-01642  Oracle GoldenGate Capture for Oracle, MY_SERVICE.prm:  BOUNDED RECOVERY: recovery end position: SeqNo: 11932, RBA: 25311476, SCN: 1.353105371 (4648072667), Timestamp: 2019-12-30 16:06:40.000000, Thread: 2.
2020-02-17 14:52:38  INFO    OGG-01643  Oracle GoldenGate Capture for Oracle, MY_SERVICE.prm:  BOUNDED RECOVERY: CANCELED: for object pool 1: p49266_extr.
2020-02-17 14:52:38  INFO    OGG-01579  Oracle GoldenGate Capture for Oracle, MY_SERVICE.prm:  BOUNDED RECOVERY: VALID BCP: CP.MY_SERVICE.000002823.
2020-02-17 14:52:38  INFO    OGG-01629  Oracle GoldenGate Capture for Oracle, MY_SERVICE.prm:  BOUNDED RECOVERY: PERSISTED OBJECTS RECOVERED: <<NONE TO RECOVER>>.
2020-02-17 14:52:40  WARNING OGG-02045  Oracle GoldenGate Capture for Oracle, MY_SERVICE.prm:  Database does not have streams_pool_size initialization parameter configured.
2020-02-17 14:52:40  INFO    OGG-02248  Oracle GoldenGate Capture for Oracle, MY_SERVICE.prm:  Logmining server DDL filtering enabled.
2020-02-17 14:54:47  INFO    OGG-00987  Oracle GoldenGate Command Interpreter for Oracle:  GGSCI command (oracle): info all.
2020-02-17 14:55:41  ERROR   OGG-02037  Oracle GoldenGate Capture for Oracle, MY_SERVICE.prm:  Failed to retrieve the name of a missing Oracle redo log.
2020-02-17 14:55:41  ERROR   OGG-00662  Oracle GoldenGate Capture for Oracle, MY_SERVICE.prm:  OCI Error retrieving bind info for query (status = 100).
2020-02-17 14:55:41  ERROR   OGG-01668  Oracle GoldenGate Capture for Oracle, MY_SERVICE.prm:  PROCESS ABENDING.
```

Comment: 'Select sequence# from v$archived_log where 4648072667 is between first_change# and next_change#;' - ORA-00908: missing NULL keyword

Answer (score 1):

Your EXTRACT process is looking for archived REDO log files from six weeks ago (2019-12-30), and those log files are no longer available.

If you must have your EXTRACT pick up where it left off, you will need to restore the missing archive logs starting with sequence 11932 and then restart the EXTRACT.

If you are OK with your EXTRACT starting over without extracting transactions from the last six weeks, you can delete the EXTRACT and then add it again.

There is also a middle-ground where you can reposition the EXTRACT to the oldest archive log that the DBMS knows about and then start the EXTRACT.